# How to make an object drop when leaving trigger zone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an object drop when exiting the "trigger" zone in my game.  So what happens is when I enter the trigger zone the objects start floating.  But when I leave the zone the object doesn't drop back to the ground, it just stops in mid air when i enter the trigger zone again it continues to float?

Here is my script for floating:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Floatinga : MonoBehaviour {

public float horizontalSpeed;
public float verticalSpeed;
public float amplitude;

 private Vector3 tempPosition;

 void Start () 
 {
 tempPosition = transform.position;
}

 void FixedUpdate () 
 {
 tempPosition.x += horizontalSpeed;
 tempPosition.y += verticalSpeed;
 transform.position = tempPosition;
 }
}
```

And then when I enter or exit:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Floating : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject otherObject;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    otherObject.GetComponent<Floatinga>().enabled = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    otherObject.GetComponent<Floatinga>().enabled = true;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void OnTriggerExit ()
{
    otherObject.GetComponent<Floatinga>().enabled = false;

}
}
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong?  Can any one please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a rigidbody and set useGravity to true.

Comment: No, its not working.  The object just starts floating without me entering the trigger zone and seems to be bouncing all over the seen now.

Comment: Because your FixedUpdate is setting the position of your object and at the same time the gravity is acting on it. You should disable the gravity when you want the object to float, and enable gravity, disable that floating script when you want it to drop.